# JSF inputText inside foreach doesn't work

Tags: jsf, foreach, jstl

I study JSF and can't set a value in my bean from **`<h:inputText>`** inside **`<c:foreach>`**
Here is my code.

**JSF page**:

```
<h:form>
    <c:forEach items="#{commentController.getComments(request.getParameter('item_id'))}" var="comment" varStatus="loop">
        <div class="comment">
            <span class="user">#{comment.user.name}</span>

            <h:outputText value="#{comment.text}" rendered="#{!commentController.editMode}" styleClass="text"/>
            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{commentController.editMode}">
                <h:inputText value="#{comment.text}"/>
                <h:commandButton action="#{commentController.changeComment(comment)}" value="Save">
                    <f:param name="item_id" value="#{request.getParameter('item_id')}"/>
                </h:commandButton>
                <h:commandButton immediate="true" action="#{commentController.switchEditMode}" value="Cancel">
                    <f:param name="item_id" value="#{request.getParameter('item_id')}"/>
                </h:commandButton>
            </h:panelGroup>

            <span class="date">#{comment.date}</span>

            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{commentController.isCurrentUsersComment(comment)}">
                 <h:commandLink rendered="#{!commentController.editMode}" action="#{commentController.switchEditMode}" value="Change comment ">
                     <f:param name="item_id" value="#{request.getParameter('item_id')}"/>
                 </h:commandLink>
                 <h:commandLink rendered="#{!commentController.editMode}" action="#{commentController.deleteComment(comment)}" value="Delete comment"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </div>
    </c:forEach>
</h:form>
```

**Bean**:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Comment {

private int id;
private User user;
private String text;
private Date date;
private int itemId;

public Comment() {

}


public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public int getItemId() {
    return itemId;
}

public void setItemId(int itemId) {
    this.itemId = itemId;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

**Controller**:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class CommentController {

private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
private boolean editMode = false;

public CommentController() {

}

public String addComment(Comment comment) {
    java.util.Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    int itemId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("item_id"));
    comment.setUser((User)request.getSession().getAttribute("current_user"));
    comment.setDate(new Date(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDay())); //bug
    comment.setItemId(itemId);
    DBUtils.addCommentForItem(comment);
    return "/pages/item.xhtml?item_id=" + itemId +"&faces-redirect=true";
}

public String changeComment(Comment comment) {
    DBUtils.changeCommentForItem(comment);
    return switchEditMode();
}

public String deleteComment(Comment comment) {
    DBUtils.deleteCommentForItem(comment);
    return "/pages/item.xhtml?item_id=" + comment.getItemId() +"&faces-redirect=true";
}

public boolean isCurrentUsersComment(Comment comment) {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    User currentUser = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("current_user");
    return currentUser.equals(comment.getUser());
}

public String switchEditMode() {
    editMode = !editMode;
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    int itemId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("item_id"));
    return "/pages/item.xhtml?item_id=" + itemId +"&faces-redirect=true";
}

public List<Comment> getComments(int itemId) {
    comments = DBUtils.getCommentsForItem(itemId);
    return comments;
}

public boolean isEditMode() {
    return editMode;
}
}
```

Constantly after pushing button **'Save'** this method gets old bean. I've tried to use **varStatus** in **`<c:forEach>`** and written something like this:

```
<h:inputText value="#{commentController.getComments(request.getParameter('item_id'))[loop.index].text}">
```

where **`varStatus="loop"`**, but it hasn't helped. 
Perhaps I used it in a wrong way, I don't know. Please help. If it's necessary, I'll add other parts of my code.

Comment: <c:foreach> is a loop and you placed a <form> inside it (among other things), which doesn't seem to make sense. The code is trying to create multiple forms (inside the loop) but I think you don't want that. Also, why this line #{commentController.getComments(request.getParameter('item_id'))}. You haven't posted a CommentController but I think there's probably an easier way to obtain a reference to the list.

Comment: Do you think that the problem is in controller? Should I post its code? @dsp_user

Comment: Yes, post the code, and as I said it's unusual to place a <form> inside <c:foreach>.

Comment: I've rewritten page and added controller's code @dsp_user

Comment: Why do you expect to get a new bean? You're calling getComments with an old ID (request.getParameter('item_id'))

Comment: In this line  <f:param name="item_id" value="#{request.getParameter('item_id')}"/> you setting idem_id with an old id. Try to hardcode some value just to see that it's working e.g.  <f:param name="item_id" value="3"/>

Comment: item_id is special for every item.xhtml page. I want to change a comment on the particular page with the particular item_id. If I use another item_id, I'll get another page with according item_id. Why should I use another item_id?

`<h:commandButton action="#{commentController.changeComment(comment)}" value="Save">
                                            <f:param name="item_id" value="3"/>
                                        </h:commandButton>`

I've written that and got an exception @dsp_user

Comment: What exception? Anayway, when you click Save, what do you expect to get? It's not clear from your post what you have on your page before Save is clicked and what should be displayed after it has been clicked? I suggest that you edit your answer and show us exactly what you're getting now and what you expect.

Comment: I have some comments on a page. When I click on the link "Change comment" for some comment, inputText appears and I can change a text of the comment. But when I click "Save" button, old text value from bean is saved into DB. That's the problem. InputText doesn't change the field in my bean. Sorry for the unclear question and thanks for your patience @dsp_user

Comment: OK, now I think I understand. I think your problem is that your changeComment() method executes before the setter (setText) so you get  an old value (JSF lifecycle) from the controller. You can  use a listener for this purpose (<f:ajax tag) or possibly change your changeComment to accept a String (new comment) and then call settext from the method (not clean admittedly)

Answer (score 0):

You've set the var parameter of the c:foreach to the same name as your request scoped Comments managed bean. So the first thing I'd suggest is removing the managed bean annotations from your Comment class; based on the code you've presented there's no reason for it to be one.